# how can Map.Entry interface call getValue()/getKey() methods without creating objects?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Here is the scenario:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> st=hashMap.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> me : set)
{
  System.out.println(me.getKey()+":"+me.getValue());
}
```

Now my question is if Set,Map,Entry all are interfaces and getKey() and getValue() are the methods inside Entry interface how can Map.Entry call them without creating object ?

Comment: If you are learning and you got this question, you are on right path. Such question means you are moving in right direction. I would suggest you to see as how Iterator is returned from Collection classes like ArrayList. Iterator is an interface , its implementation is returned, (implementating iterator classe is private)

Comment: @nits.kk yes I'm a beginner.Thank You so much for your advice.

Comment: the basic idea is *Expose the interface hide the implementation*  . Usually method return type is the Interface and from side the method hidden implementation is returned. This keeps the users of such code (libs) decoupled from implementation. Implementating class can change without the users being affected.

Comment: Can you please tell which class implements these two methods?? I didn't create any object of the class that implements Map.Entry. Let me clarify what I'm saying:: Let say A is an interface and has method met(); now B implements A therefor A obj=new B(); now I can say obj.met()...so if HashMap implements Map.Entry then where is the HashMap object? When I say Map.Entry<String,Integer> me : set , me is just a reference varible isn't it? Would you please answer @nits.kk

Comment: See my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977344/504133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my commet to the answer :

The basic idea is **Expose the interface hide the implementation** . Usually method return type is the Interface and from in side of the method hidden implementation is returned. This keeps the users of such code (libs) decoupled from implementation. Implementating class can change without the users being affected.

Now your query about

```
Set<String,Integer> st=hashMap.entrySet();
```

HashMap source code has a inner class which implements Set. The method entrySet() is present in HashMap which returns *an object of that class which implements Set*.  The return type in the signature is  Set and not *that implementing class*, but it is the object of the concrete class implementing the Set interface that is returned.

This way authors of HashMap.java have hidden the implementation from you. They can at their will change the implementing class in new versions of Java. Only they need to take care that their new implementing class implements Set interface.

It is similar to below code.

```
public interface InterfaceExposed{
      public void task();
} 

public class A{
     private class Implementation implements InterfaceExposed{
       public void task(){
             // some code to do task as per current implementation.
       }
     }
     public IExposedInterfaceOfA similarToEntrySet(){
          return new Implementation();
    }
}
```

Now users of class A will be dependent upon exposed interface and will not know and not depend on hidden private Implementation.

```
 A a = new A();
 IExposedInterfaceOfA xyz =    a.similarToEntrySet();
 xyz.task();
```

Here you see xyz as being of type IExposedInterfaceOfA but it refers to object of Concrete class Implementation.

Comment: Set<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> mapEntries = hmap.entrySet();
List<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> lst2=new ArrayList<>();
lst2.addAll(mapEntries);
Collections.sort( lst2, new Comparator<Entry<Integer,String>>() 
  {


            public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer,String> ele1, Entry<Integer,String> ele2) {

                                    return ele1.getValue().compareTo(ele2.getValue());

            }

        });

I'm not getting this code,here I'm not calling entrySet then how ele1 and ele2 accessing getKey and getValue?

Comment: Your first line in comment has `Set<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> mapEntries = hmap.entrySet();` mapEntries refers to EntrySet object returned. and ArrayList's addAll method adds all the elements of the set `mapEntries`. Now as each element of the arraylist is of type `Map.Entry` and it has `getKey()` and `getValue()`

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` has an internal implementation for all these interfaces.

For example, there's an `EntrySet` class which is used as the implementation of the `Set` returned by the `entrySet()` method:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
}
```

And there are several classes that serve as the implementation of `Map.Entry`.

For example:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

Comment: One quick question, as getKey() and getValue() all are defined inside Entry so do I need to always call Map.Entry or just Entry is enough?
e.g. for(Entry<String,Integer> me : set)  ??

Comment: @SuvamRoy If you `import java.util.Map.Entry;` you can refer to it with `Entry` instead of `Map.Entry`.

Comment: Another question sir, Where is the HashMap object ?

Comment: @SuvamRoy I don't understand the question.

Comment: Let say A is an interface and has method met(); now B implements A therefor A obj=new B(); now I can say obj.met()...so if HashMap implements  Map.Entry then where is the HashMap object? When I say Map.Entry<String,Integer> me : set , me is just a reference varible isn't it?

Comment: @SuvamRoy `HashMap` doesn't implement `Map.Entry`. HashMap contains nested classes, such as `HashMap.Node`, that implement `Map.Entry`. `me` is a variable holding a reference to an object that implements the `Map.Entry` interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165773/discussion-between-suvam-roy-and-eran).

Answer (score 0):

The `Set` and the `Entry` objects are created internally in the `Hashmap` class. If you see the source code for `java.util.Hashmap` and visit the `entrySet()` method, you would see that it creates a concrete `EntrySet` (which extends the `AbstractSet` class which in turn implements the `Set` interface) object for you. It is this object that you are referencing as `Set`. Similarly, `Hashmap` provides an internal implementation of the `Entry` class, one of them being `Node`, that you would again find the source code. I would strongly recommend that you visit the source code.

As Linus Torvalds says,

> Talk is cheap, show me the code

Answer (score 0):

**Class composition over inheritance.**

`entrySet` method's definition returns an object of a nested class `EntrySet`.

`EntrySet` is a concrete class that implements `Map.Entry` interface.

`Entry` is also a concrete class that implements `Map.Entry` interface.
`Entry` class defines the `getKey` and `getValue` methods.

`EntrySet` and `Entry` are classes composed in the HashMap class.
So when you instantiate an object of `HashMap`, you avail these methods.

[HashMap source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java)